# Problem deploying a flask application with apache, 2it displays the directory

Tags: python, flask, apache2.4

I have installed python3.10 and libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3, apache2.4

Voila mon virtualhsot

/default-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

            DocumentRoot /var/www/html

            # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
            # error, crit, alert, emerg.
            # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
            # modules, e.g.
            #LogLevel info ssl:warn

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

            # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
            # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
            # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
            # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
            # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
            #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

            #   SSL Engine Switch:
            #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
            SSLEngine on

            #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
            #   the ssl-cert package. See
            #   /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz for more info.
            #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
            #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
            SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key



            WSGIScriptReloading On
            WSGIDaemonProcess  threads=5
            WSGIScriptAlias /base-co /var/www/html/base-co/app.wsgi

             <Directory /var/www/html/base-co>
                 WSGIProcessGroup base-co
                 WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                 Order deny,allow
                 Require all granted
             </Directory>
            #   Server Certificate Chain:
            #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
            #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
            #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively


    </VirtualHost>
```

file
**init**.py

my file  app.py

```
    from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def test():
    return "Coucou !"
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

and app.wsgi

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import logging
import sys
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/base-co/')
from app import app 
application.secret_key = 'changemoilacle'
```

the problem that after deploimenet, my application displays the directory instead of the home page (hello)
and for information I have already hosted other php applications on the same server and that's why my flask application is in a subdirectory.
Thanks for your help